# Helping icons classes used for captcha like refresh, headphones, help not showing on browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, captcha

i used captcha in my register user page with that i used icons of refresh, headphones, help but captcha, text box everything is displaying on browser and working fine also even refresh, headphones, help icons are also working well but problem is that istead of showing refresh, or headphone, or help icon in browser only a squre is showing, plz give me any idea how i can show this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            var RecaptchaOptions = {
                theme: 'custom',
                custom_theme_widget: 'recaptcha_widget'
            };
    </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=6LcrK9cSAAAAALEcjG9gTRPbeA0yAVsKd8sBpFpR"></script>
<div id="recaptcha_widget" class="form-recaptcha">
                <div class="form-recaptcha-img" style="width: 325px">
                    <a id="recaptcha_image" href="#"></a>
                    <div class="recaptcha_only_if_incorrect_sol display-none" style="color: red">
                        Incorrect please try again
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="input-group" style="width: 325px">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recaptcha_response_field" name="recaptcha_response_field"/>
                    <div class="input-group-btn">
                        <a class="btn default" href="javascript:Recaptcha.reload()">
                            <%--<img src="../logo/refresh.jpg" alt="" />--%>
                            <i class="fa fa-refresh"></i>
                        </a>
                        <a class="btn default recaptcha_only_if_image" href="javascript:Recaptcha.switch_type('audio')">
                            <i title="Get an audio CAPTCHA" class="fa fa-headphones"></i>
                        </a>
                        <a class="btn default recaptcha_only_if_audio" href="javascript:Recaptcha.switch_type('image')">
                            <i title="Get an image CAPTCHA" class="fa fa-picture-o"></i>
                        </a>
                        <a class="btn default" href="javascript:Recaptcha.showhelp()">
                            <i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <p class="help-block">
                    <span class="recaptcha_only_if_image">Enter the words above </span>
                    <span class="recaptcha_only_if_audio">Enter the numbers you hear </span>
                </p>
            </div>
```

Comment: check the location and existence of the icons.

Comment: everything is present

Comment: Show us the css that contains the images. I'm sure it is a path issue

Answer (score 0):

i did it, simply i make a folder in my .aspx page and in that folder i place the icons like refresh, headphones etc and after that i give the path of image

```
<div class="input-group-btn">
                        <a class="btn default" href="javascript:Recaptcha.reload()">
                            <i>
                                <img src="../logo/glyphicons_081_refresh%20-%20Copy.png" class="fa fa-refresh" />
                            </i>
                        </a>
                        <a class="btn default recaptcha_only_if_image" href="javascript:Recaptcha.switch_type('audio')">
                            <i title="Get an audio CAPTCHA">
                                <img src="../logo/glyphicons_076_headphones%20-%20Copy.png" class="fa fa-headphones" />
                            </i>
                        </a>
                        <a class="btn default recaptcha_only_if_audio" href="javascript:Recaptcha.switch_type('image')">
                            <i title="Get an image CAPTCHA">
                                <img src="../logo/glyphicons_138_picture@2x%20-%20Copy.png" class="fa fa-picture-o" />
                            </i>
                        </a>
                        <a class="btn default" href="javascript:Recaptcha.showhelp()">
                            <i>
                                <img src="../logo/glyphicons_194_circle_question_mark%20-%20Copy.png" class="fa fa-question-circle" />
                            </i>
                        </a>
                    </div>
```